# Wont the 6v charging voltage destroy the 3.8v super capacitor in this circuit sculpture?

Tags: circuit-protection, supercapacitor

I'm impressed with the circuit sculpture given at following link and want to build one for myself.

https://www.bhoite.com/sculptures/tiny-cube-sat/

For circuit diagram pls see this https://www.bhoite.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/tinycubesat-1-720x340.png

I looked up the part numbers and their specifications. So my question is the solar cells in series will give approx 6v and after passing through the 1N4148 diode there will be a forward voltage drop of say 0.72v which is approx 5v output. Isn't this voltage higher than the super cap rated for 3.8v? Will it not damage the super cap?

Comment: The top line voltage spec for most solar cells is often the open circuit voltage.  Under load that voltage will not be reached.  You would need to refer to the loaded output spec.

Comment: Thanks Nedd! I looked at the solar panel datasheet. It says V at Max power point is 2.23v. In this case the series voltage will be 4.46v and after forward voltage drop will be 3.74v which is lower than 3.8v rating for super cap. Is this what you meant? Sorry I'm a newbie so may have understood your answer wrongly.

Comment: Super capacitor or ionistor max voltage 2.7V due to chemistry. Connecting in series may increase max voltage but reduce capacity value. Overvoltage may destroy the device.

Comment: @OmkarS.Bapat It can be higher or lower than max power point. There may be a chart showing the voltage vs current

Comment: I'm not sure about supercaps, but some kinds of batteries can handle very slow overcharge without any permanent damage. Anyone know if it's the same for supercaps?

Comment: @user253751 no, it's not the same for caps as batteries. there are margins on cap ratings, so it's usually fine, but according to the datasheet, it's not guaranteed not to explode at 0.1v extra.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! But I'm still not clear whether the charging voltage in the original circuit diagram will damage the super cap or it will not and I'm missing something here

Comment: You might also keep in mind that as shown the assembly is more of a concept design rather then an actual cube-sat design.  Likely none of the parts shown would be rad-hard or capable of withstanding the vacuum or temperature swings of a low earth orbit environment.